# Ray having head trauma explanation in Fractured?

Tags: plot-explanation, fractured

In the Netflix movie ***Fractured***, after Ray accidentally kills his wife and finds his daughter killed, he creates his own reality where his wife and daughter are alive.

Does Ray hit his head so bad that causes him this trauma or is it because of losing his ex-wife years ago that caused this?

Also does he suffer this trauma from a long time or was this after he caused his wife's death?

Why is Ray hell bent on accusing the hospital responsible for his wife and daughter's disappearance. Why can't he see the reality even after noticing his wife's and daughter's body in his own car?

2nd scene: why didn't police's sniffer dogs track Ray's car at the accident site? Since his wife and daughter were in Ray's car all this while. Or was this also one of the realities he created?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question will be closed as too broad because you are asking more than one question at a time which isn't allowed on this site. Please edit this to ask only one question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the plot synopsis on [the movie's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractured_(2019_film)):

> However, as Ray drives away it is revealed that he is experiencing visual hallucinations from psychological trauma resulting from the incident earlier that day. In reality, Peri died from the fall, and Ray accidentally killed Joanne after pushing her. **The trauma of realizing he'd killed his family caused Ray's mind to construct a new reality** in which both his wife and daughter are alive. Ray believes he is rescuing them, but it is revealed that he has kidnapped a random patient from surgery, while his wife and daughter are lying dead in the trunk of his car.